# rename file names work in command prompt but not in bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to rename commands in a bash script. If I run for example:

```
echo /home/scientist/mySalesData/campaignData_1482386214.24417.csv  | sed 's/\(.*\)\(_.*\)/mv \"&" \"\1.csv\"/' | bash
```

It works fine and gives me campaignData.csv in the directory `/home/scientist/mySalesData/` .

However, if I put this in a bash script as follows:

```
for f in /home/scientist/SalesData/*; do
if [ -f "$f" ]; 
  cp "$f" /home/scientist/SalesForce/SalesData/Backups/                                                                
  echo $f$ | sed 's/\(.*\)\(_.*\)/mv \"&" \"\1.csv\"/' | bash |        
fi 
done
```

I get:

```
mv: cannot stat '/home/scientist/SalesData/campaignData_1482386214.24417.csv$': No such file or directory
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have a simple typo. Change `$f$` to `"$f"` and add the missing `then`.

Comment: What I get for doing this late at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd "$srcdir"
for f in *; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    cp "./$f" "$dstdir/${f%_*}.csv"
  fi
done
```

The `%` is the [*strip shortest suffix pattern*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) operator.

Comment: oh that's neat. Learned something new with that operator.

Answer (score 2):

You have a trailing `$` here:

```
echo $f$
```

remove that (and quote the expansion):

```
echo "$f"
```

You could use here string too:

```
sed ... <<<"$f"
```